# Were princes and other large landowners motivated to support the Reformation by the frequency of Church holidays?

Tags: catholic-church, protestant-church, reformation

Church holidays or holy days were very frequent in the middle ages. Here is one link [Medieval Holidays](http://www.medieval-life-and-times.info/medieval-england/medieval-holidays.htm) that testifies this:

> "The rural population of the Middle Ages had their days of rest and amusement, Middle Ages holidays were then much more numerous than at present. At that period the festivals of the Church were frequent and rigidly kept, as each of them was the pretext for a forced holiday from manual labour."

My understanding has been that the Roman Catholic Church levied heavy fines upon those landowners who worked the land on these days. Were many large landowners in Germany and elsewhere motivated by avoiding frequent Church holidays as they supported the reformation?

Comment: Remember that the "*work week*" was six days not seven, and with no *annual vacation* or *long weekends* - so the *Church Holidays* often merely substituted for those 65 or so days (52 Saturdays + 10 vacation days + 3 long weekends) off that we take for granted.

Comment: What has your research shown?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I am interested in the contrast between holidays before and after the reformation in protestant ares, and my question relates the matter to what motives large landowners and princes may have had for supporting the reformation. 

http://www.medieval-life-and-times.info/medieval-england/medieval-holidays.htm

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I am not a historian, and am asking. Hopefully some will have interesting answers.

Comment: Our expectation (like most SE sites) is that you'll have done [preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/1401) before asking the question. Also, [don't reply in comments; edit the question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3915/1401).  Those aren't criticisms; just advice.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Thanks, I added some more information and will add some more to improve the question.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal   Isn't Medieval England looking at the wrong spot?  The English Protestant phenomenon is a different, later, thing than the Martin Luther Reformation in Germany/Holland and had different motivations.  You'd get a partial answer to your question if you find that Church holidays, and overall time off was reduced in Germany/Holland right after Protestantism got established there.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosopher Indeed, there may have been differences between the different protestant countries as regards changes in time off. Max Weber might have something to say about the topic.